# Struggling with visualizing (drawing) a sample of a random process

Tags: random-process, stationary

I've had this question I don't really know how to answer. 
let $t \ge 0$, $N_t$ is a possionian random process with parameter 1. let $-\infty < t < \infty$, $X_t$ is a random process that is stationary with expectation $\mu$ and autocorrelation $R_X(\tau)$ statistically independent of $N_t$. $X_t \ge 0 \forall t$ 
let $-\infty <t <\infty \quad  Y_t = N(X_t)$. Draw a sample of $X_t$,$Y_t$,$N_t \ge 0$ 
**my attempt** 
drawing a poissonian process with parameter one is easy to draw, I'll draw an ascending staircase where each step's height is 1 and the steps are random in time. the process will start at 0.

for drawing $X_t$'s sample I'll draw a "noisy" continuous line that stays at about the same height - i think?

 I'm utterly stumped as to how to draw $Y_t$ - i know at any point in time t it's essentialy the height of the staircase at "time" = $X_t$ but it still seems very incomprehensible to me.

Comment: So $N(X_t)$ is really $N_{X_t}$? I was confused at the change in notation — subscript versus parentheses.

Comment: I think so - here’s a link to how the original (in hebrew) question looks https://imgur.com/a/0poBpTc(hebrew is written from right to left)